# Cast array of objects to a different array of objects

Tags: c#, casting

I am pulling back information about locations from a webservice. The service returns an array of `WebObjectsDTOs` which holds all of the objects. The objects can be of different types but in this case I'm requesting only objects of type `MlaLocation`.  I then need to orderby the locations name. The problem I ran into was that I cannot do an orderby on `searchResult.WebObjectDTOs` because it's the base object and does not have access to the location name.

I thought my solution would be to cast `searchResult.WebObjectDTOs` to `MlaLocationDTO[]` since `searchResult` is only returning an array of `MlaLocationDTO`. But what I'm seeing in debug is that `mlaLocations` is being set as null even though `searchResult.WebObjectDTOs` has objects in it.

```
MlaWebObjectServiceClient svc = new MlaWebObjectServiceClient();
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(){
    OperatingCompanyId = Guid.Parse("e4be5383-03d0-4a99-9613-6238dd2396ad"), 
    WebObjectType = "MlaLocation"
};
SearchResult searchResult = svc.GetMlaWebObjects(searchRequest);
MlaLocationDTO[] mlaLocations = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs as MlaLocationDTO[];
rptLocationsList.DataSource = mlaLocations.OrderBy(m => m.Name);
rptLocationsList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Array casting is odd in C#, and, as far as I know, you must iterate through each of the items in the array and cast them directly into the new array.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII you don't need to iterate.  See the link in my answer.  For example, `object[] a = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }` is legal.

Comment: @phoog correct downwards casting is fine, but upwards casting is different, in that it will not implicitly work.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII you're right in this case.  However, it's not the upcast per se; it depends on the actual runtime type of the array.  This was the source of my confusion.  This is fine: `object[] a = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }; string[] b = (string[])a;` But this is not: `object[] a = new object[] { "a", "b", "c" }; string[] b = (string[])a;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your collection has many other types of objects, you can safely filter `MlaLocationDTO` objects using the [`OfType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var mlaLocations = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs.OfType<MlaLocationDTO>();
```

If all of the objects were `MlaLocationDTO`, you can use the [`Cast` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) instead:

```
var mlaLocations = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs.Cast<MlaLocationDTO>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast your array to the type;

```
var mlaLocations = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs.Cast<MlaLocationDTO>();
```

See [Enumerable.Cast Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to perform this cast because, in this case, the array of `WebObjectDTO` is not an array of `MlaLocationDTO`. Consider a simpler example, assume you have

```
class Alpha { }
class Beta : Alpha { } 

Alpha[] alphas = new Beta[10]; // supported via array variance
Beta[] betas = (Beta[])alphas; // legal cast, the array is actually of this type

Alpha[] alphas2 = new Alpha[10];
Beta[] betas2 = (Beta[])alphas2; // not legal, the array isn't of this type
```

Each element in the array could very well be an `MlaLocationDTO`, but unless the *array* itself is an array of these objects, you cannot perform this cast. It will blow up at runtime, as you have seen in your code.

As for solutions, *if* `MlaLocationDTO` has an inheritance relationship with `WebObjectDTO` where `MlaLocationDTO : WebObjectDTO` and *if* each object in the array *is in fact* a `MlaLocationDTO`, you can cast each individual element.

```
var locations = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs.Cast<MlaLocationDTO>();
```

However, if the locations are not truly this type of object, then you'll just need to define the conversion yourself. It is simple enough to do this in query form.

```
var locations = from location in searchResult.WebObjectDTOs
                select new MlaLocationDTO
                {
                    Name = ...,
                    Id = ...,
                    /* etc. */
                };
```

Optionally include `.ToArray()` on either of the query forms if you need an array result. The type would then be `MlaLocationDTO[]`. Sans the `ToArray()` invocation, it would simply be `IEnumerable<MlaLocationDTO>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to do that:

```
searchResult.WebObjectDTOs.Select(d => d as MlaLocationDTO).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
MlaLocationDTO[] mlaLocations = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs as MlaLocationDTO[];
```

try this:

```
MlaLocationDTO[] mlaLocations = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs.Cast<MlaLocationDTO>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
IEnumerable<MlaLocationDTO> castedResults = searchResult.WebObjectDTOs.Cast<MlaLocationDTO>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looping through the WebObjectDTOs and adding values to mlaLocations:
May be:

```
 for(int objIndex = 0; objIndex <= WebObjectDTOs.Count - 1; objIndex++)
 {
      mlaLocations[objIndex].Add(WebObjectDTOs[objIndex]);
 }
```

or something similar?